# File locked SSIS

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis, integration

I have a package that needs to process a file and then move it to archive folders. This is my current setup:

[image]

The first move works fine. The second one is the issue here.This works for all my child packages except one. It partially works. When the import is successful the file is locked and can't be moved. When the import fails, it can be moved.The child package that is causing the issue has an ADO.net connection. that is the only difference from the other ones. I have tried a 1 minute wait before trying to move again. I have also tried doing a rename and moving from a script task.

Also the retainConnection is set to false.

Ask for more info if needed. I am out of ideas on this one.

EDIT: The error message is " The file cannot be moved because it it used in another process "

Comment: I had the same issue, when I tried to process the same file in parallel. Do you have such logic?

Comment: Put the "MoveToProcessed" step outside the ForEach loop.

Comment: No the file is not being processed in parallel.

Comment: What's the specific message you're getting?